# Need to prove inequality for any $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

Need to prove for any $a,b∈\Bbb R$
$$
\left|\sqrt{|a|+1}-\sqrt{|b|+1}\right|≤\frac{|a-b|}2
$$
I tried to simplify and got:
$$
\frac{\big||a|+|b|\big|}{\sqrt{|a|+1}+\sqrt{|b|+1}}≤\frac{|a-b|}2
$$

Comment: I edited your post to make the math more readable, but it's possible that I missed some things. Could you please check that what stands there now is what you wanted to say?

Comment: Yes, Thank you !

Comment: What happens if $a>b$?  Or the opposite?

Comment: it's still valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do a couple of simplifications. For one, on the left-hand side, you only have $|a|$ and $|b|$, and if you change the left-hand side to be $\frac{||a| - |b||}{2}$ it can only become smaller. So we might just as well just say $a, b\geq 0$ and be done with all the small absolute value signs.

Next, the expression is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, so we may as well assume $a\geq b$. In that case we can do away with all the absolute value signs, and what we're left with showing is
$$
\sqrt{a + 1}-\sqrt{b+1}\leq \frac{a-b}2
$$
Now, going from here, you had a great idea: multiply the left-hand side by $\frac{\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}}{\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}}$. However, you made a small but crucial mistake in the calculation, and I think that's a big reason why you're stuck. Instead of what you have, we get
$$
\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}}\leq \frac{a-b}2
$$
(You have $a+b$ in the left-hand numerator.) From here the rest is rather simple: Divide both sides by $a-b$, then note that each of the square roots is greater than or equal to $1$, and you're done,